# Windows - How do I disable the "Wrong Volume" error message

Tags: c++, windows

My application is reading/writing data to a removable media (USB DOK) in the background. The problem is that when the USB is removed while the app is working, the computer pops up an error message:

### Wrong Volume

### The wrong volume is in the drive. Please insert volume  into drive E:.

### Cancel   Try Again   Continue

This happens during operations such as GetFileSize, ReadFile. Obviously, since the app is supposed to work in the background, I would like to suppress those messages and fail silently.

BTW - It seems that the process giving those message is not my process, but CSRSS.EXE (although the cause is definitely the operation from my process).

One direction I am considering is switching to NtQueryInformationFile, NtReadFile, etc., but I'd rather not...

Thanks

Comment: Before each access you can always check if something is connected to the port. If not don't perform the operation. If that not possible then leave as is. This is the desired way to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling:

```
SetErrorMode(SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
```

At the beginning of your main function.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The system does not display a message box when it fails to find a file. Instead, the error is returned to the calling process.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you properly disconnect your hardware using the icon in the windows system tray so that it's not being accessed when you pull it out of the drive. Or at least exit your ap first.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not possible. The user may disconnect the USB when and how he decides to. My application should not be visible to the user regardless.

Comment: I'd suggest leaving this as it is. If the user wishes to remove the drive without properly unmounting then they should expect to receive odd error messages.